# How to mirror movement of faces

Tags: modeling

On both sides of the model i have indentical faces. I want to move them both closer to center. Is there any way to copy my editing but with negative axis. For example i move one face along x axes for 2, then another face also moves for but for x -2.[image]

Comment: From the screen as shown, it's a scale?  Switch pivot to 'Median' select both faces, SY + drag, or numerical entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you have a mirror modifier applied. You have to cut your model in half then apply the mirror modifier to apply transformations in both sides at the same time

Comment: The Mirror modifier does have a bisect feature, so cutting the model in half is optional.